# Matrix chain rule question: what is $\frac{d}{dX} f(S)$ where $S = (A+X)^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I'm trying to find the following derivative: $$\frac{d}{dX} f(S)$$ where $f$ is a function that takes a matrix and returns a scalar, and $S=(A+X)^{-1}$. Assume that we know what $\frac{d}{dS} f(S)$ is (for example, if $f(S)=\exp(u^\intercal S u)$, we'd have $\frac{d}{dS} f(S)=u u^\intercal f(S)$).

I want to employ something like a matrix chain rule that looks like $$\frac{d}{dX} f(S) = \left(\frac{dS}{dX}\right) \left(\frac{d}{dS} f(S)\right)$$
but the problem is that the $\left(\frac{dS}{dX}\right)$ doesn't seem to make sense, and I don't know how to do a matrix-by-matrix derivative.

If it helps, assume that all matrices are symmetric and PSD.

Comment: If you asked me to, I couldn't prove it, but I guessed at the answer and it's giving me perfect results in my application, so if anyone needs it: $$\frac{d}{dX} f(S) = S \left(\frac{d}{dS} f(S)\right) S$$
This is only for my particular case where $S=(A + X)^{-1}$.
If someone could prove this, or better yet, figure out a more general rule when $S = T(X)$, that'd be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know how to calculate the gradient with respect to $S$ 
$$G=\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}$$ 
We also know that
$$\eqalign{
 X &= S^{-1} - A\cr
 dX &= -S^{-1}\,dS\,S^{-1} &\implies dS = -S\,dX\,S \cr
}$$
Let's use this to write the differential of the function, and then perform a change of variables to find a result in terms of $X$ 
$$\eqalign{
 df &= G:dS \cr
  &= -G:S\,dX\,S \cr
  &= -S^TGS^T:dX \cr
  &= -S^T\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}\,S^T:dX \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}  &= -S^T\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}\,S^T \cr
}$$
where colon denotes the inner/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
and the cyclic properties of the trace give rise to some rules for rearranging the product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
 A:BC &= AC^T:B \cr
 A:BC &= B^TA:C \cr
 A:BC &= BC:A \cr
}$$

As you've discovered, the chain rule can be difficult to apply to matrix problems when the intermediate quantities, i.e. matrix-by-matrix or vector-by-matrix derivatives, are higher-order tensors.

The virtue of the differential approach is that the differential of a matrix behaves like an ordinary matrix.

Comment: Give a man a fish or teach a man to fish. Thanks a lot. I'll always know to use that differential approach now.

Comment: greg, how would we do it if $S = X \otimes A $?

Comment: My attempt is written as this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989932/whats-frac-partial-partial-x-fx-otimes-a

Comment: @Greg, sorry for all the questions, but where did you learn this notation?