# Applying the chain rule to a function mapping matrices to matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

Given a function $F:\text{Mat}(n,n)\rightarrow\text{Mat}(n,n)$, I'd like to get $\frac{d}{dM_{ij}}F(M)^2$ using matrix calculus.

I already derived it by simply writing it out explicitly for my choice of $F$, but this doesn't seem to generalize well if I want to take second derivatives of higher powers of $F(M)$ so I wanted to finally get my head around matrix calculus.

To get it in matrix notation I noted that $$\frac{d}{dM_{ij}}F(M)^2 = \left(\frac{d}{dM} F(M)^2\right)[e^{ij}]$$ for $e^{ij}\in\text{Mat}(n,n)$ such that $(e^{ij})_{xy} = \delta_{i=x}\delta_{j=y}$.

Now if $F$ were the identity, then I'd get $Me^{ij}+e^{ij}M$ (or more generally $\sum_{l=0}^{p-1}M^le^{ij}M^{p-l-1}$ for $F(M)^p$ instead of $F(M)^2$). **Using the chain rule, would I get** $$\left(F(M)e^{ij}+e^{ij}F(M)\right)\left(\frac{d}{dM}F(M)[e^{ij}]\right) ?$$

**Optional information**:

It seems weird since I multiply(/pass as an argument) with $e^{ij}$ twice, which doesn't really make a lot of sense in the scalar case (e.g. $n=1$), but

1. I don't know how to make use of the $(\frac{d}{dX} X^2)[Y]=XY+YX$ otherwise
2. for symmetric $M$ and my choice of $F$ (which maps positive $M$ to positive $F(M)$) the trace of this object coincides with my direct computation (not sure if that's just a coincidence caused by some of the involved symmetries though).

What I looked up so far: Most of the notes I could find online only dealt with scalar valued functions of matrices or vectors. http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf (p15, eq 136) seems to be one exception, but they go back to pretty direct computations which is basically what I did so far.
Instead I was thinking about getting something along the lines of [Matrix chain rule question: what is $\frac{d}{dX} f(S)$ where $S = (A+X)^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391112/matrix-chain-rule-question-what-is-fracddx-fs-where-s-ax-1) (just set $f=(F(M)^2)_{xy}$), but this doesn't seem to work if I don't know how to invert $F$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Nice first question!

Answer (score 3):

Let a colon (:) represent the double-contraction product, e.g.
$$\eqalign{C &= A:B \cr C_{ijmn} &= A_{ijkl}\,B_{klmn}}$$
Also, let ${\mathcal E}$ denote the 4th order isotropic tensor with components
$${\mathcal E}_{ijkl}=\delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl}$$
I'll assume that you know how to calculate the function $F$ 
and its gradient ${\mathcal G}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial M}$.

Then the differential and gradient of your squared function are
$$\eqalign{
 S &= F^2 \cr
dS &= dF\,F + F\,dF \cr
   &= ({\mathcal E}F^T+F{\mathcal E}):dF \cr
   &= ({\mathcal E}F^T+F{\mathcal E}):{\mathcal G}:dM \cr
\frac{\partial S}{\partial M} &= ({\mathcal E}F^T+F{\mathcal E}):{\mathcal G} \cr
}$$
If you are uncomfortable with tensors, then you can vectorize all of the terms, i.e.
$s={\rm vec}(S), f={\rm vec}(F),$ etc, to obtain
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(dS) &= {\rm vec}(dF\,F + F\,dF) \cr
ds &= (F^T\otimes I+I\otimes F)\,df \cr
   &= (F^T\otimes I+I\otimes F)\,G\,dm \cr
\frac{\partial s}{\partial m} &= (F^T\otimes I+I\otimes F)\,G \cr
}$$
where $G=\frac{\partial f}{\partial m}$ is a matrix, not a 4th order tensor like ${\mathcal G}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm really confused by all the different notations I've seen so far. By $dF$ do you mean the 4-tensor $(dF_{ij}/dM_{kl})_{ijkl}$? I guess by $\mathcal E F^T$ you don't mean the outer product $\mathcal E F^T = (\mathcal E_{ijkl}F_{nm})_{ijklmn}$ since it wouldn't work out with the dimensions to make your double-contraction with $dF$ well-defined, but I'm not sure how to canonically "multiply" a 4-tensor ($\mathcal E$) with a 2-tensor ($F^T$) to get a 4-tensor.

Comment: Juxtaposition implies a single-contraction product, e.g. $${\mathcal H}=F{\mathcal E} \implies {\mathcal H}_{ijkl}=F_{ip}{\mathcal E}_{pjkl}$$ which is an example of a 2-tensor multiplied by a 4-tensor yielding another 4-tensor.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on the definitions (in particular dimensions) of the tensors you introduce here? I don't see the equality going from $dF\,F+F\,dF$ to $(\mathcal EF^T+F\mathcal E):dF$ after trying to write it out explicitly several times.

Comment: Okay, let's expand at the $(F{\mathcal E}:dF)$ term $$\eqalign{F_{ip}{\mathcal E}_{pjkl}\,dF_{kl} &= F_{ip}\delta_{pk}\delta_{jl}\,dF_{kl}\cr&=F_{ik}\,dF_{kj}\cr F{\mathcal E}:dF &= F\,dF}$$

Answer (score 2):

In index notation, with the Einstein summation convention, the solution is quite simple 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial S_{pq}}{\partial M_{ij}} 
&= \frac{\partial(F_{pk}F_{kq})}{\partial M_{ij}}
\cr
&= \frac{(\partial F_{pk})F_{kq}}{\partial M_{ij}} 
+ \frac{F_{pk}\,(\partial F_{kq})}{\partial M_{ij}} 
}$$

Comment: This is essentially what I did by direct computation, although admittedly it's much prettier using the Einstein summation convention. I should have been clearer about what I meant by "matrix calculus", but I didn't know how to call it. Should I edit the question to include "tensor calculus"? Not sure whether that's a thing.