# Can you please help verify if the derivatives of loss with respect to weights, bias, and input data of a single layer neural network are correct?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

I am trying to calculate the derivatives of the loss w.r.t weights, bias, and input for a single-layered neural network where the loss function is mean squared error. The derivation is as follows:-

$\bullet~$ Let the weight column vector, input data, bias,and output column vector be
 $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $\mathbb{b} \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^m$

$\bullet~$Let $\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{X}\times\mathbf{W}+\mathbb{b}$ be the linear transformation

$\bullet~$$\hat{\mathbf{Y}} = \max(0,\mathbf{Z})$ be the relu activation

$\bullet~$$L = (\hat{\mathbf{Y}} - \mathbf{Y})^T(\hat{\mathbf{Y}} - \mathbf{Y})/\left|\mathbf{Y}\right|$ be the mean squared error
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial \hat{\mathbf{Y}}} = \frac{2}{\left|\mathbf{Y}\right|}(\hat{\mathbf{Y}} - \mathbf{Y})^T \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times m}\\
&\frac{\partial \hat{\mathbf{Y}}}{\partial \mathbf{Z}} = \text{diag}\bigg(\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_1}{\partial Z_1},\dots ,\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_m}{\partial Z_m}\bigg) \in \mathbf{R}^{m\times m},~
\text{ where } \frac{\partial \hat{Y}_i}{\partial Z_i} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } Z_i \leqslant 0 \\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{Z}} = \frac{2}{\left|\mathbf{Y}\right|}(\hat{\mathbf{Y}} - \mathbf{Y})^T\times \text{diag}\bigg(\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_1}{\partial Z_1},\dots ,\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_m}{\partial Z_m}\bigg) \in \mathbf{R}^{1\times m}
\end{align*}

---

$\blacksquare~$**For weights:**
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}}{\partial \mathbf{W}} = \mathbf{X} \in \mathbf{R}^{m\times n}$$
Hence,
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{W}} = \frac{2}{\left|\mathbf{Y}\right|}(\hat{\mathbf{Y}} - \mathbf{Y})^T\times \text{diag}\bigg(\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_1}{\partial Z_1},\dots ,\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_m}{\partial Z_m}\bigg) \times \mathbf{X} \in \mathbf{R}^{1\times n}$$
In order the make the dimensions of $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{W}}$ same as $\mathbf{W}$, we need to take transpose of the above equation. This makes the RHS -
$$\mathbf{X}^T\times \text{diag}\bigg(\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_1}{\partial Z_1},\dots ,\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_m}{\partial Z_m}\bigg)^T\times \frac{2}{\left|\mathbf{Y}\right|}(\hat{\mathbf{Y}} - \mathbf{Y}) \in \mathbf{R}^n$$
**My first question is** -$\color{blue}{\text{ Is the above derivation correct? Or am I missing something?}}$

---

$\blacksquare~$**For bias:**
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}}{\partial\mathrm{b}} = \mathbf{1} \in \mathbf{R}^m$$
Hence,
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathrm{b}} = \frac{2}{\left|\mathbf{Y}\right|}(\hat{\mathbf{Y}} - \mathbf{Y})^T\times \text{diag}\bigg(\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_1}{\partial Z_1},\dots ,\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_m}{\partial Z_m}\bigg) \times \mathbf{1} \in \mathbf{R}^{1\times 1}$$
**My second question-** $\color{blue}{\text{Is the above expression correct?}}$

---

$\blacksquare~$**For data**
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{W} \in \mathbf{R}^n$$
Hence,
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \frac{2}{\left|\mathbf{Y}\right|}(\hat{\mathbf{Y}} - \mathbf{Y})^T\times \text{diag}\bigg(\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_1}{\partial Z_1},\dots ,\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_m}{\partial Z_m}\bigg) \times \mathbf{W}$$ $\color{red}{\text{Which is not correct because of the mismatch of the dimensions}}$

**The only way this will work is as follows:**
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{W}\times \frac{2}{\left|\mathbf{Y}\right|}(\hat{\mathbf{Y}} - \mathbf{Y})^T\times \text{diag}\bigg(\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_1}{\partial Z_1},\dots ,\frac{\partial \hat{Y}_m}{\partial Z_m}\bigg)$$
$\color{magenta}{\text{This seems to be just wrong to me.}}$ Can you please help me in understanding what is going wrong here?

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were doing pretty good until you got to
$\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial X}$

The problem is that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial X}$
is not a matrix but rather a 3rd order tensor!

The simplest way to avoid such tensors in matrix calculus
is to use *differentials*.

First a bit of notation
$$\eqalign{
z &= Xw + {\tt1}\beta \\
dz &= dX\,w
\qquad&({\rm the\,differential\,of\,}z) \\
{\cal H}(z_k) &= \begin{cases}1\quad{\rm if}\quad z_k>0\\0\quad{\rm otherwise} \end{cases}
\qquad&({\rm Heaviside\,step\,function}) \\
h &= {\cal H}(z)
\qquad&({\rm apply\,the\,function\,elementwise}) \\
H &= {\rm Diag}(h)
\qquad&({\rm diagonal\,\{{\tt0},\!{\tt1}\}\,matrix}) \\
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(A^TB)
\qquad&({\rm Frobenius\,product}) \\ \\
}$$
The [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) affords a more succinct way to write one of the earlier gradients
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\hat y}{\partial z} &= H
}$$
Next rewrite one of the previously calculated gradients in differential
form and then perform the change of variables $z\to X$
$$\eqalign{
d{\cal L}
 &= \left(\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial z}\right):dz \\
 &= 2\|y\|^{-1}H(\hat y-y):dz \\
     &= 2\|y\|^{-1}H(\hat y-y):dX\,w \\
     &= 2\|y\|^{-1}H(\hat y-y)w^T:dX \\
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial X}
     &= 2\|y\|^{-1}H(\hat y-y)w^T \\
}$$
And now the dimensions work out perfectly (although it appears that your preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) is the transpose of this).

The key is that the differential of a matrix is just another matrix and obeys all of the rules of matrix algebra. This is simply not true for tensors.

Not only that, but it's impossible to write tensor expressions
unless/until you learn [index notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539632/applying-the-chain-rule-to-a-function-mapping-matrices-to-matrices/2540518#2540518).

#### Update

This update is to clear up some questions in the comments.

Here is a list of the sizes of the various variables
and products which occur in the solution
$$\eqalign{
\beta &\in {\mathbb R}^{1\times 1} \\
w &\in {\mathbb R}^{n\times 1} \\
h,y,\hat y,z &\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times 1} \\
X &\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \\
H &\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times m} \\
Xw,\,Hy &\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times 1} \\
Hyw^T &\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \\
}$$
The properties of the trace function permit the terms in a
Frobenius product $(:)$ to be rearranged in a number of equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
&A:B = B:A = B^T:A^T \\
&A:BC = AC^T:B = C^T:BA^T = etc \\
}$$
Note that the matrix on each side of the product symbol (i.e. the colon)
is exactly the same size. This is the same requirement as the
Hadamard product. In fact, the Frobenius product can be defined as
a Hadamard product $(\odot)$ followed by summation.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_i\sum_j (A\odot B)_{ij} \\
}$$
Finally, a gradient and a differential are two ways of conveying the
same information
$$\eqalign{
df = G:dX\qquad\iff\qquad G=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\right)\\
\\
}$$

#### Update #2

Here are the differentials of $z$.
$$\eqalign{
z &= Xw + {\tt1}\beta \\
dz &= dX\,w \quad&({\rm wrt\,}X) \\
dz &= X\,dw \quad&({\rm wrt\,}w) \\
dz &= {\tt1}\,d\beta\quad&({\rm wrt\,}\beta) \\
}$$
This post has already established that
$$\eqalign{
\hat y &= \max(z,0) \\
d\hat y &= H\,dz \\
\frac{\partial\hat y}{\partial z} &= H \;=\; H^T
 \quad ({\rm it's\,symmetric}) \\
}$$
Let's calculate $\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial\hat y}$
$$\eqalign{
{\cal L} &= \|y\|^{-1}(\hat y-y):(\hat y-y) \\
d{\cal L} &= 2\|y\|^{-1}(\hat y-y):d\hat y \\
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial\hat y} &= 2\|y\|^{-1}(\hat y-y) \\
}$$
Substituting $\,d\hat y=H dz\,$ yields
$$\eqalign{
d{\cal L} &= 2\|y\|^{-1}(\hat y-y):H\,dz \\
 &= 2\|y\|^{-1}H^T(\hat y-y):dz \\
 &= 2\|y\|^{-1}H(\hat y-y):dz \\
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial z} &= 2\|y\|^{-1}H(\hat y-y) \\
}$$
The other gradients are obtained by substituting $dz$ with 
the appropriate differential, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
d{\cal L} &= 2\|y\|^{-1}H(\hat y-y):dz \\
 &= 2\|y\|^{-1}H(\hat y-y):{\tt1}\,d\beta \\
 &= 2\|y\|^{-1}{\tt1}^TH(\hat y-y):d\beta \\
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial\beta}
 &= 2\|y\|^{-1}{\tt1}^TH(\hat y-y) \\
}$$

Comment: So, just to be clear, the other two parts are correct?

Comment: Three questions - 
1. How did $w$ become $w^T$?
2. $:$ symbol in the solution is the Frobenius product as per your notation,right?
3. The dimension of $H(.)$ in the last equation is $1\times m$ and the dimension of   $w^T$ is $1\times n$. How are these two compatible?

Comment: thanks for the clarification. There is one question still lingering though. In the equation just after $d{\cal L} = \left(\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial z}\right):dz$, $\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial z}$ looks like transposed term of the product given in the question. I understand it is needed to make the dimensions equal. Does this mean you took the transpose in this step deliberately or is it the consequence of something else? Rest everything is making sense except this step. Thanks again

Comment: But the sizes that I am using are the same as yours. Every vector is a column vector. That is the reason that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}$ is coming the way it is in my solution. I have been using the numerator notation given in https://explained.ai/matrix-calculus/index.html

Comment: Your question states explicitly that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}\in{\mathbb R}^{1\times m}$ which is a row vector. My convention is to use column vectors for such gradients.

Comment: I understand. The reason this is coming up is how the calculation has been carried out. In my question, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \hat{\mathbf{Y}}}$ is an $\mathbb{R}^{1\times m}$ vector because that is how the calculation turns out. $\hat{\mathbf{Y}}$ still is $m\times 1$ vector only. Similarily, $\frac{\partial \hat{\mathbf{Y}}}{\partial \mathbf{Z}}$ is an $\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ matrix because that is how the calculations turn out to be. If I take the matrix product, the final answer is $1\times m$ dimensional vector. I am sorry but I unable to follow the concept of convention here.

Comment: I've updated the post with my gradient calculations. You'll note that they are the transposes of your gradients.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help. Could you please suggest a resource where I can learn all these things? Thanks