# transpose appearing for the chain rule in the matrix form

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am trying to understand deriving the derivative of a matrix equation of the form:

$$a = \tanh(WX + b)$$
in which $W$ is a $M*N$ matrix, $X$ is $N*1$, and $b$ is $M*1$. I'm trying to take the derivative of $a$ with respect to $W$, $X$, and $b$. I already have the final answers as:

1. $$\partial a/ \partial X= W^T(1 - \tanh(WX+b)^2)$$
   I don't understand how $W$ moves to the left hand side of $(1 - \tanh(WX+b)^2$ and gets transposed!? I understand that the chain rule is:

$$\partial f(u)/ \partial x= f'(u)\partial u/ \partial x$$ so in my example $\partial u/ \partial x$ is on the right hand side of the equation.

2. $$\partial a/ \partial W=(1 - \tanh(WX+b)^2)X^T$$
   in which I don't understand how $X$ gets transposed and moves to the left hand side.

Comment: $WX+b$ seems to be a $m\times 1$ vector. How do you define the hyperbolic tangent of a vector? Defining powers of a vector is tough.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg I think it is applied component-wise.

Comment: But then the derivatives would have to be taken component-wise as well! Notation seems a little vague...

Comment: yes tanh and power of 2 is component wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the variables
$$\eqalign{
 y &= Wx+b \cr
 a &= \tanh(y) \implies A = {\rm Diag}(a) \cr
}$$
Now calculate the differential and gradient of $a$ wrt $x$
$$\eqalign{
da &= (1-a\odot a)\odot dy \cr
   &= (I-A^2)\,dy \cr
   &= (I-A^2)W\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} &= (I-A^2)W \cr
}$$
Depending on your [Layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions), you might prefer the transpose of this result
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} &= W^T(I-A^2) \cr\cr
}$$
Note that the gradient of a vector wrt a vector produces a matrix result. Your second question is about the gradient of a vector wrt a matrix, which will produce a $3rd$ order tensor.
$$\eqalign{
da &= (1-a\odot a)\odot dy \cr
   &= (I-A^2)\,dW\,x \cr
   &= (I-A^2){\mathcal H}x:dW \cr
\frac{\partial a}{\partial W} &= (I-A^2){\mathcal H}x \cr
}$$ 
The above steps use several different product notations which you may not be familiar with
$$\eqalign{
\lambda &=A:B &\implies \lambda = \sum_i\sum_j A_{ij} B_{ij} \cr
L &=A\odot B &\implies L_{ij} = A_{ij} B_{ij} \cr
C &= AB &\implies C_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik} B_{kj} \cr
}$$
The symbol ${\mathcal H}$ is a $4th$ order tensor with components
$${\mathcal H}_{ijkl} = \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl}$$

Comment: just out of curiosity and from the learning perspective, the first derivative, i.e., $\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}$ is comprehensible. However, the solution of the second derivative, i.e., $\frac{\partial a}{\partial W}$ is tricky. I hope someday I will get these tensors. Can we instead vectorize ${\rm vec}(Wx + b)$ such that the differential would be $(x^T \otimes I) {\rm vec}(dW)$? What do you say?

Comment: Vectorization is certainly one way to handle things, but the real solution is to avoid higher-order tensors entirely. Nobody really cares about them, but they **need** them as an intermediate quantity in a chain rule calculation. Here's an example my approach to such problems 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391112/matrix-chain-rule-question-what-is-fracddx-fs-where-s-ax-1/2391337#2391337

Comment: thanks for your enlightenment, greg! I have already liked your solution. I am learning a lot of matrix derivatives from you, must admit. Thank you.